# Converting a time-based string to ISO format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, html, datetime

I have an `Song` object that has a duration attribute (string based) that goes by minutes and seconds. I want to output this as a `datetime` attribute for a `<time/>` tag (via Rails) but needed to convert it to ISO 8601 format in order for it to be semantically valid.

So, I have the duration, `"2:30"`. The characters `'PT'` would need to be prepended while removing the colon in between the two numbers and finally appending the letter `'S'` at the end:

```
PT2M30S
```

Final output:

```
<time itemprop="duration" datetime="PT2M30S">2:30</time>
```

How would I go about in accomplishing this?

Is there a Ruby method that accomplishes this already? Does a regular expression have to be written out in order to find/replace the aforementioned characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't take a regex or anything fancy to do this. I'd simply split on the colon, and pass the result into a format string:

```
'PT%sM%sS' % "2:30".split(':') # => "PT2M30S"
```

---

> How does the modulo operator work in this case? Never seen something done like this before.

It's not the "modulo operator" unless it's being applied to a number. It's a String method named `%` that is an equivalent to `format` or `sprintf`. See [`String.%`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-25) followed by [`Kernel::sprintf`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) for more information, but basically:

```
  s   | Argument is a string to be substituted.  If the format
      | sequence contains a precision, at most that many characters
      | will be copied.
```

So:

```
'%s'   % 'foo' # => "foo"
'%5s'  % 'foo' # => "  foo"
'%-5s' % 'foo' # => "foo  "
'%1s'  % 'foo' # => "foo"
'%.1s' % 'foo' # => "f"

'%s = %s' % ['a', 1] # => "a = 1"
```

In particular, note that in the last one `1` is converted to `"1"` when inserted into the string. This can be useful but it isn't the only way, (or even a preferable way) to convert from an object to a string.

---

Finally, don't assume regular expressions are the way to go for every problem requiring extracting information from a string. If you can do it without resorting to weird work-arounds, use the built-in methods, like `split`:

```
require 'fruity'

compare do
  _split { 'PT%sM%sS' % "2:30".split(':') }
  _regex { "2:30".sub(/(.*):(.*)/, "PT\\1M\\2S") }
end
```

Which results in:

```
# >> Running each test 2048 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> _split is faster than _regex by 19.999999999999996% ± 10.0%
```

Regular expressions are flexible but that usually comes at the price of being slower.

Also, we see a lot of misuse of `gsub` when `sub` should be used. `sub` does a lot less work than `gsub`; Where `sub` fires once, `gsub` will continue to loop until it hits the end of the string. That is a measurable difference, even on a short string such as `"2:30"`:

```
compare do
  _sub { "2:30".sub(/(.*):(.*)/, "PT\\1M\\2S") }
  _gsub { "2:30".gsub(/(.*):(.*)/, "PT\\1M\\2S") }
end

# >> Running each test 2048 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> _sub is faster than _gsub by 2x ± 0.1
```

Comment: How does the modulo operator work in this case? Never seen something done like this before.

Comment: See the added content.

Comment: Thanks again. Appreciate the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it in elegant way try [ruby-duration](https://github.com/peleteiro/ruby-duration) gem

Example code

```
Duration.new(:weeks => 1, :days => 20).iso8601 => "P3W6DT0H0M0S"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would turn this into a method...

```
> "2:30".sub(/(.*):(.*)/, "PT\\1M\\2S")
=> "PT2M30S"
```

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer. Just one question though. What do the two backslashes represent in the second argument of the `sub()` method?  You'll have to excuse me, my RegEx fluency isn't quite there yet.

Comment: `\1` and `\2` represent the values captured in the match, but since they're inside double-quotes, they need to be doubled up. \\ is a *literal* backslash character in that context.

Comment: Take a look at the simple benchmarks at the end of my answer. Jumping to using a regular expression can be costly. Be discerning when looking to use them.